# How to print Array of Object in java

Tags: java

Assuming there is a Class called Product which has two product object called p1 and p2 which have the following fields:

> P1--> int productId =123, String name ="iPhoneS8", int unitPrice
>   =1000, String datMfs ="12/18/2017". P2--> int productId =124, String name ="Samsung Galaxy S8", int unitPrice =1200, String datMfs
>   ="05/22/2016".

The first question is

> 1), Write a java code for the product including getters and setters
>   methods, any three overloaded constructors including default. My
>   solution code is the following.

```
class Product {
    Product() {//default Constractor

    }

    Product(int price) {//Overloaded Constractor1

    }

    Product(String name) {//Overloaded Constractor2

    }

    Product(String name, double pri) {//Overloaded Constractor3

    }

    Product(int name, double pri) {//Overloaded Constractor4

    }
      // The following is the product fields   

    private int productId;
    private String name;
    private int unitPrice;
    private String dateMdft;
//The following is getters and setters

    public int getproductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(int productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    public String getproductName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setProductname(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getproductunitPrice() {
        return unitPrice;
    }

    public void setUnitPrice(int unitPrice) {
        this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
    }

    public int getUnitPrice() {
        return unitPrice;
    }

    public void setDateMan(String dateMdft) {
        this.dateMdft = dateMdft;
    }

    public String getDateManftd(String dateMdft) {
        return dateMdft;
    }
```

The second Question is

> 2), Write a method called printOutedDatedProduct(from the above) and
>   iterate through the object and print out the data for only the
>   outdated product to the screen in **CSV format**. the method should print 
>   **124, Samsung Galaxy S8,1200, 5/22/2016**.

I am really Struggling to write the method and print out the outdated product so I really appreciate the community if anybody helps me and I am also really open to take any comments as far as the solution to the first question is concerned too. Great Thanks!

Comment: There should be a constructor which sets values of all fields.

Comment: It should be CSV not CVS. What is an "outdated product" ?

Comment: This appears to be a homework assignment with little research effort being shown.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the simplest way to print a Java array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to store date in `LocalDate` object. Why LocalDate? It is a well-written and tested class for date mainetenance. 
How to instantiate and compare:

```
LocalDate d1 = LocalDate.of(2000, 06, 26);//YYYY-MM-DD
LocalDate d2 = LocalDate.now();

System.out.println(d1.compareTo(d2));//if d1 < d2, returns negative integer (difference between dates), otherwise positive integer.
```

What does `d1.compareTo(d2)`? It returns an integer representing the difference bwtween dates. It takes the first terms of dates that don't match and subtracts the second from the first. For example: `2019-03-14` compared to now (`2019-03-29`) will return `14-29 = -15`.

You need to call `compareTo(LocalDate)` method for each LocalDate field of `Product` instance and compare with `LocalDate.now();`. When the numer is negative, print info about the product.

Answer (score 0):

Java by default calls the `toString` method when you try to use an `object` as a `String` then what you need to do is to prepare the `Product` `toString` method first like this below:

```
public String toString(){
   return productId+", "+name+", "+unitPrice+", "+dateMdft;  
}
```

after that, the printing is going to be easy but you need to check for the `date`, manipulating a `date` as a `String` will cost you a lot. you can find `java` dates best practices presented in a good way [here](https://hackernoon.com/going-on-a-date-with-java-9bdac2c950b3)

after you learned how to use the `Date` `class` and how to check your date now you all you need to write the function that loops on the array you have and checks the date and `print` your data.

Answer (score 0):

First, think about right datatypes for fields. You can use String for date filed, but how will you compare this dates? There is powerful JDK [datetime API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html), let's use it. I'll recommend [LocaDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html), as you need only date part.

Second. Your constructors shouldn't be empty or useless. You could initialize object fields in constructors. For example:

```
Product(String name) {
    this(name, 0);
}

Product(String name, int unitPrice) {
    this(name, unitPrice, LocalDate.now());
}

Product(String name, int unitPrice, LocalDate dateMdft) {
    this.name = name;
    this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
    this.dateMdft = dateMdft;
}
```

The next step is method for string representation of object. You could override [toString](https://www.baeldung.com/java-tostring) or create another.

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/YYYY");

@Override
public String toString() {
    return productId + "," + name + "," + unitPrice + "," + dateTimeFormatter.format(dateMdft);
}
```

And the last, filter and print.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
    products.add(new Product("1", 100, LocalDate.now().minusDays(1)));
    products.add(new Product("2", 150, LocalDate.now().minusDays(2)));
    products.add(new Product("3", 250, LocalDate.now()));

    System.out.println("Via for loop:");
    for (Product p: products) {
        if (p.getDateMdft().isBefore(LocalDate.now())) {
            System.out.println(p);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Via stream API:");
    products
            .stream()
            .filter(p -> p.getDateMdft().isBefore(LocalDate.now()))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```